# Cache external files and Webpage to show in offline

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, local-storage, browser-cache

To view the rich media content like Image, PDF, web links, Documents, ppt in offline mode. Currently, I am opening rich media content in the new tab using window.open(/*-------*/). How can i cache richmedia contents so that it is servered from cache when offline.